# Application.Run of Addins Macro

Tags: excel, vba

Been researching previous treads on this issue but I still cannot find a solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Trying to use `Application.Run` to to call a sub called `SortSOEDM` from a module called `SOMacros` in an Addin called `CDVAddins2010.Xlam` that was published to me by a colleague. I've tried dozens of iterations of the following line using the module name and sub name in different positions. Can not get it to work. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
Application.Run ("CDVAddins2010.xlam!SortSOEDM")
```

Issue resolved by Doovers. See his answer below.

Comment: That line looks correct - what happens?

Comment: Run time error 449. Argument not Optional

Comment: That means you need to supply an argument to the sub, and you haven't.

Comment: @Rory Thanks. Sorry to be a pain but you're dealing with a self taught less than amateur here. Could you give me an example how/what I should   change?

Comment: I can't be more specific than: `Application.Run "CDVAddins2010.xlam!SortSOEDM", "some parameter"` since I have no idea what is required by the sub you are calling! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Application.Run` expects the following arguments:

```
Application.Run([Macro], [Arg1], [Arg2], ...)
```

The reason you are getting the "Argument not Optional" error is that `CDVAddins2010.xlam!SortSOEDM` `Sub` or `Function` is expecting a parameter to be passed to it.

So for example, if `SortSOEDM` looked like this:

```
Sub SortSOEDM(str As String)
    MsgBox str
End Sub
```

To call this you would use:

```
Dim str As String
str = "Test Message"
Application.Run "CDVAddins2010.xlam!SortSOEDM", str
```

Or if it was a function:

```
Function SortSOEDM(str As String)
    SortSOEDM = "The string you passed to this function was: " & str
End Function
```

Which you would call like this:

```
Dim str As String
str = "Test Message"
Dim strReturn As String
strReturn = Application.Run("CDVAddins2010.xlam!SortSOEDM", str)
MsgBox strReturn
```

Note that you only use () for a function.

Comment: Thank you! Tried for almost an hour. Ended up removing ()

Answer (score 0):

In the VBA editor, add a reference to the addin: Tools > References, then Browse and change the file type to .xlam. Use this dialog to find the add-in on your hard disk.

You can then call the subroutine without Application.Run:

```
' call the subroutine
SortSOEDM
```

Comment: Hi Bob, sorry but could you explain a bit more please. Am I browsing to the CDVAddins2010.xlam file on the C drive in order to edit its file extension. Apologies but I'm not familiar with this menu.

Comment: Exactly. Once this is complete, in the VBA editor's Project Explorer (where you see the list of modules), alongside the folders "Microsoft Excel Objects" and "Modules" you will see a new one called "References". See also my edit

Comment: Ok did that but getting this warning, "Name conflicts with existing module, project, or object library". Does this mean the Reference is already established? If so I do not see any level in the Project Window called "References"

Comment: Sounds like it didn't work to me. You can confirm this by making sure your VBA project is selected in the Project Window, going to Tools > References. If it did work you will see the add-in at the top of the list, ticked